# Local ActiveMQ instance forwards/changes an http message to remote activemq instances

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Using version 5.13.3 - we have created a local instance of activeMQ on our db server so we can send an http message from the sql server database to a queue,  Upon receipt of an http message would like to create a new json message to be sent to remote activemq cluster with a couple of attributes that were in the http message body...(there would be five instances in the cluster - any one of them could be recipient)  can anyone tell me how I might be able to accomplish this?  is it possible to do this?

Just as a note: This is just to send messages - NEVER expect a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a very simple camel route that could run very efficiently within the same Java VM as the ActiveMQ Broker. Use the vm:// transport, and a Velocity template to pre-define the structure of the message

ref: http://camel.apache.org

Note: Camel was developed out of the ActiveMQ project for exactly this type of use case.